# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2 ERROR with Mybatis

Tags: java, sql, spring, mybatis

I have a Mapper class like this in my Application tha is trying to call a procedure in the database, and i checked like 3000 times the the type and positios og the parameters are right, but it throws and sqlException, now i will show you the Code of the Mapper

```
@Mapper
public interface HoraFechaExtractoMapper {

    @Select(value="{ CALL PACKAGE.PROCEDURE("
            + "#{P_tpno, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},"
            + "#{Registro.pPeriodicidad, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR},"
            + "#{Registro.pHora, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR},"
            + "#{Registro.pDia, mode=OUT, jdbcType=NUMERIC})}")
    public void getHoraFechaExtracto(@Param("P_tpno") String p_tpno,@Param("Registro") Registro registro);
}
```

and My Registro Class that is a Parameter for the methos Mapper is like this

```
public class Registro implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2014497735552490495L;
    
    /** The p periodicidad. */
    @JsonProperty("p_periodicidad")
    private String pPeriodicidad;
    
    /** The p hora. */
    @JsonProperty("p_hora")
    private String pHora;
    
    /** The p dia. */
    @JsonProperty("p_dia")
    private Integer pDia;

    /**
     * Gets the p periodicidad.
     *
     * @return the p periodicidad
     */
    public String getpPeriodicidad() {
        return pPeriodicidad;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the p periodicidad.
     *
     * @param pPeriodicidad the new p periodicidad
     */
    public void setpPeriodicidad(String pPeriodicidad) {
        this.pPeriodicidad = pPeriodicidad;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the p hora.
     *
     * @return the p hora
     */
    public String getpHora() {
        return pHora;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the p hora.
     *
     * @param pHora the new p hora
     */
    public void setpHora(String pHora) {
        this.pHora = pHora;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the p dia.
     *
     * @return the p dia
     */
    public Integer getpDia() {
        return pDia;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the p dia.
     *
     * @param pDia the new p dia
     */
    public void setpDia(Integer pDia) {
        this.pDia = pDia;
    }

}
```

But when Mybatis is preparing the statement it throws this error

```
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: { CALL PACKAGE.PROCEDURE(?,?,?,?)}
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException:  Missing IN or OUT parameter at index::  2
    Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
```

It is very likely that the error is in the mapper, but i can't find the error, maybe you could see it

Comment: What is the "argument mode" of the second parameter? If it's `IN` then it should be easy to perform the call from Java; anything else (like `OUT` or `INOUT`) could be tricky to call from outside the database engine.

Comment: What's the database? Looks like Oracle.

Comment: This is the facade of the procedure ->
Procedure PROCEDURE(  p_tpno          in  varchar2,
                                      p_periodicidad  out varchar2,
                                      p_hora          out varchar2,
                                      p_dia           out number
                                         )

Comment: Thanks it was the missing Option annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you need

```java
@Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
```

after Select annotation